# Difference between C7 Compatible and Program Database

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I found very little information on the difference between `C7 compatible` and `Program Database` (there is a third one, Program Database Edit and Continue, but that should be the same as Program Database with the ability to edit and continue). The only solid information I could find was that `C7 compatible` embeds the debug information in the obj files, while the `Program Database` creates a `.pdb` file for debugging purposes.

Is there an upside to using `C7 compatible` vs. `Program Database`? What is the downside?

> Extra notes: I have tried both and so far, the debugging information is preserved properly in both cases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is documented in [Generating and Deploying Debug Symbols with Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260783(VS.60).aspx)  which makes it still relevant today as C7 hasn't changed.

Comment: Good link. Did I understand this correctly: PDB gives you Edit & Continue, C7 avoids having an additional file around?

Comment: All the information I needed was in that link, thank you! I did not get that link whenever I searched for this

Comment: @Samaursa my pleasure to have found it. It helps to know what the link is telling you when searching IYSWIM...